# How to rebuild Symfony Encore assets?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, webpack-encore

I have installed the Symfony demo application (https://github.com/symfony/demo) and tried to play around with assets/encore. My understanding of encore is:

1. You include js/css with

```
{{ encore_entry_link_tags('css/app') }}
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('js/app') }}
```

2. You edit js/css within assets/js and assets/css
3. You "rebuild" assets which then are stored in public/build/js and public/build/css

I changed some of the css and js code and am strugling with the rebuild part. I have tried

```
php bin/console assets:install
```

But after reloading the demo page, nothing changes.

How can I rebuild the assets?

Comment: Loremo, have you seen the anwers below? Do you have any feedback on them?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have [all the necessary parts installed](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html):

#### To compile your assets once, on development

```
yarn encore dev
```

#### To keep a watcher that will recompile your assets automatically when changes are detected on your files (kill it with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>):

```
yarn encore dev --watch
```

#### To compile your assets for production/deployment:

```
yarn encore production
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to yivi's answer:

Firstly, your third assumption is not completely correct. All build files (if you haven't touched any config) will be stored in `/public/build`. There are not separate directories for css and js.

Secondly, if you look in `package.json` you will find a section with `scripts`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch",
    "build": "encore production --progress"
  }
```

There scripts define aliases to executable. So instead of running `yarn encore dev --watch` from your terminal, you could simply run `yarn watch`.

Thirdly, a very usefull feature is running `yarn dev-server`. This will create a development server on the fly that watches any updates to your asset files and automatically reloads your browser when a change is detected.

ps. just to be sure: you will need the package manager [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/) (or you could use something like [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install))